# Synchronize access and delete item in a list from different threads.

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a list of objects. While one thread will add or remove objects in this list depending on some conditions. While other thread will access objects in this list. 
Ex:

```
List<node*> list


Thread1:

 {
   list.append(node);
   list.removeOne(index);
   ............

 }
Thread2
{

   Node* node = list.at(index);
   if(node)
     doSomething(node);
}
```

How to Thread2 avoid accessing null pointer when executing doSomething(node) but node is delete from thread1 ;

Comment: You'll be needing `mutex` for the `list`. Search for `client` `server` problems in `c++` since this isn't really a concrete problem.

Comment: @TonyD, sorry I was referring to Reader-Writer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While this can be solved using standard lock mechanism (see mutex), you may want to look into the Reader-Writer specific synchronization primitive. It will allow to have more than one reader, but only one writer can process the list at a time.